# Prefixing imported CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

The purpose of my React app (built with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) is to be embedded inside other websites ("widget"), rather than a standalone application.

So I provide websites owners with minified JS and CSS files, they insert it to a webpage by adding `<script src="my-module.min.js">` and `<link href="my-module.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`.
Then when calling some global function, my app presents itself modally with its UI, on top of the hosting website.

In order to avoid style conflicts, I make sure to prefix my CSS classes with something unique to my module - so as an example, instead of the class `page-container`, I would name it `my-module-123-page-container`.
This way if the hosting website has a class called `page-container`, then my module won't override its properties, but rather use the unique `my-module-123-page-container` class.

My problem is with imported CSS files - for example if my app depends (by `npm install`ing) on [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), some generic class names will be defined, that I do not control and cannot prefix to make it unique.

The solutions I could think of so far:

1. Splitting my app so that the actual UI will be presented in an `iframe`, this way the styles will definitely be separate from the hosting website.
2. Forking the dependency, and crazily renaming all of the classes and make all of its React components use the renamed classes.

Both options sound awful.

Anyone can direct me?
I'm sure it's not a rare concern - what do all of those products that let you embed them in your website, but have their own styling do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution for generated unique name for CSS class.

based on `npm i css-loader style-loader -D`
you can use this config in `webpack.config.js`

```
{
  loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: 1,
      localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true
    }
}
[name]_[local]_[hash:base64] It means
```

The localIdentName allows you to configure the generated identification.

[name] will take the name of your component,[local] is the name of your class/id,[hash:base64] is the randomly generated hash which will be unique in every component’s CSS

This is reference post:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75

Comment: Thanks! Now since I work with create-react-app I would either need to eject, or work with their [@next](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/next) version.